# groupby of dataframe with sort

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to sort a groupby with aggregate and `numpy.size`.

```
boarded_vl.groupby(['day_of_week', 'boarded_at']).aggregate({'boarded_at' : np.size})
```

I need this dataframe return sorted by last column `np.size`. I can't find a solution.

Comment: Please provide more codes and data for developer to work on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without example data, but the solution should be simply:

```
boarded_vl.groupby(['day_of_week', 'boarded_at']).aggregate({'boarded_at' : np.size}).sort_values('boarded_at')
```